# hi i need to add the amount $5 in each line of each id

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Is it possible to add the sum of one row for each id
id;code;type;2023-06-30;2023-07-01;2023-07-02;2023-07-03;2023-07-04;2023-07-05;2023-07-06;2023-07-07;2023-07-08;2023-07-09;2023-07-10;2023-07-11;2023-07-12;2023-07-13;2023-07-14;2023-07-15;2023-07-16;2023-07-17;2023-07-18;2023-07-19;2023-07-20;2023-07-21;2023-07-22;2023-07-23;2023-07-24;2023-07-25;2023-07-26; 018-118;speed violation;highway 27 OP RZ 27A-032 Rome "Rome",km 16 + 072;32;24225;31;25164;43;27562;40;24877;34;20993;47;26631;48;25119;3;1847;317;1;9465;2;7035;2;7556;5;7681;2;8401;(32+24225+31+25164+43+27562+40+24877+34+20993+47+26631+48+25119+3+1847+317+1+9465+2+7035+2+7556+5+7681+2+8401) 018-118;driveways;highway 27 OP RZ 27A-032 Rome, km 16 + 072;3;8416;9;9114;4;9482;4;9312;5;8459;1;8552;2;8563;5;8772;6;9006;4;11910;4;9276;5;8685;2;8261;2;(3+8416+9+9114+4+9482+4+9312+5+8459+1+8552+2+8563+5+8772+6+9006+4+11910+4+9276+5+8685+2+8261+2)

my code

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = SUBSEP = ";"
        ORS = ""
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" 
    }
    {
        date[$1]
        tuple[$3,$4,$6]
        val[$3,$4,$6,$1] = $5
    }
    END {
        print "id;code;type"
        for (i in date) print FS i
        print "\n"

        for (i in tuple) {
            print i
            for (j in date) {
                k = i SUBSEP j
                print FS ( k in val ? val[k] : "" )
            }
            print "\n"
        }
    }
' test/all.csv >test.csv
```

Comment: I don't see in your code any attempt of **adding** something?

Comment: @user1934428 that's because it appears to be a cut&paste from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77144207/10971581) to a different question (which has recently been edited to duplicate the question here)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then [edit] your question to format your input, output, and code as Code Blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to sum from **fourth** column onward, rather than `$5`, it is a simple three-line change:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {
        FS = SUBSEP = ";"
        ORS = ""
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc" 
    }
    {
        date[$1]
        tuple[$3,$4,$6]
        val[$3,$4,$6,$1] = $5
        total[$3,$4,$6] += $5  # for clarity, could just
                               #   store in tuple array
    }
    END {
        print "id;code;type"
        for (i in date) print FS i
        print FS "total\n"

        for (i in tuple) {
            print i
            for (j in date) {
                k = i SUBSEP j
                print FS ( k in val ? val[k] : "" )
            }
            print FS total[i] "\n"
        }
    }
' test/all.csv >test.csv
```